# mysql slave stuck at Reading event from the relay log all the time

Tags: mysql, slave

two days ago,i imported data through "source xxx.sql" on the master,it has 1.35million row records,the total size is 10G,the master anything is good after i executed import operate. but that it was finished on the master has passed two days,the state of slave still is "Reading event from the relay log",who can help me to resolve the problem?thanks in advance.

Below are a detail about slave status:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.1.50
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.001137
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 43132410
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.002897
                Relay_Log_Pos: 497809898
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.001130
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 497809685
              Relay_Log_Space: 40113924576
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 161225
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 0f9e9ec5-ed9f-11e5-9a4a-525400c50c20
             Master_Info_File: /data/mysql1/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event from the relay log
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Below are relay logs list on the salve:

```
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  254 Oct 15 11:17 mysql-relay-bin.002896
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  19G Oct 15 11:40 mysql-relay-bin.002897
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 161K Oct 15 11:40 mysql-relay-bin.002898
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  254 Oct 15 11:40 mysql-relay-bin.002899
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  67M Oct 15 12:10 mysql-relay-bin.002900
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  18G Oct 15 12:14 mysql-relay-bin.002901
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 112K Oct 15 12:14 mysql-relay-bin.002902
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  254 Oct 15 12:14 mysql-relay-bin.002903
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  420 Oct 15 12:14 mysql-relay-bin.002904
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 4.4M Oct 15 12:14 mysql-relay-bin.002905
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  254 Oct 15 12:14 mysql-relay-bin.002906
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  420 Oct 15 12:14 mysql-relay-bin.002907
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  254 Oct 15 12:14 mysql-relay-bin.002908
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 122M Oct 15 14:34 mysql-relay-bin.002909
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  207 Oct 15 14:34 mysql-relay-bin.002910
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 7.9M Oct 15 15:27 mysql-relay-bin.002911
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  207 Oct 15 15:27 mysql-relay-bin.002912
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 371K Oct 15 15:34 mysql-relay-bin.002913
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  207 Oct 15 15:34 mysql-relay-bin.002914
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  76M Oct 15 23:00 mysql-relay-bin.002915
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 5.3M Oct 15 23:59 mysql-relay-bin.002916
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  254 Oct 15 23:59 mysql-relay-bin.002917
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  36M Oct 16 08:05 mysql-relay-bin.002918
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 4.4M Oct 16 08:22 mysql-relay-bin.002919
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 979M Oct 16 23:00 mysql-relay-bin.002920
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 5.5M Oct 16 23:58 mysql-relay-bin.002921
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  254 Oct 16 23:58 mysql-relay-bin.002922
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  38M Oct 17 08:02 mysql-relay-bin.002923
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 6.6M Oct 17 08:53 mysql-relay-bin.002924
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  725 Oct 17 08:02 mysql-relay-bin.index
```

Answer (score 0):

See the `Seconds_Behind_Master: 161225`
line in slave status output, for now the delay is 44 hours.

Run `show slave status` few times and make a suggestion on the rate it changes, if everything is OK it should be decreasing constantly.

To speed up  the slave you can decrease a load on the server: stop querying it for a while and stop any other activity that takes place on the server.

However you may find reasonable to resetup slave from fresh dump from master, xtrabackup from percona can do it with no locks to DB (unless you use MyISAM a lot, as it suites best for innodb engine).